Node.js - Git - how to handle package-lock.json conflicts properly
The question
It is considered best practice to commit the package-lock.json into source repository.
My question is how to handle package-lock.json merging when there are some huge discrepencies between two branches.
For instance, let's imagine:

in branch 1, I added two new modules and removed one from package.json dependencies, and ran npm install
in branch 2, I changed a dependency from "~1.0.0" to "^2.0.0", and ran npm install

When merging the two branches, there will be conflicts and lots of new lines from each of the package-lock.json.
How to handle this complexity correctly?
Thanks for your help
What I've tried
I have done the operations described above with 3 modules in package.json dependencies. The resulting list of conflict to resolve was pretty big, so I'm afraid in a real life project this can become a burden.


Resolve any conflicts in the package.json and ensure its contents make sense.
Rebuild package-lock.json as normal.

npm will rewrite package-lock.json from package.json making the conflicts irrelevant and guaranteeing it matches package.json.

I agree with this answer but "ensure the merge went well" may be confusing. (How can "the merge" go well if package-lock.json still has conflicts?)

@schwern thanks for your answer. The all point of the package-lock.json is to make sure everyone (including the CI tool) works with the same version. So let's say a developer added a package with "^1.0.0" and npm installed version 1.0.0. Package-lock.json will contain version 1.0.0 and tests were made using this version. Now a new minor of the package is available. If the package-lock.json is rewrittent, it may contain this new version instead of version 1.0.0 with which the tests were run. So it would seem it is important that package-lock.json is merge as well.

@JChauveau Yes, you must rerun tests after a code change and before accepting. This applies to merges, too. Your situation is no different. Your branch review process should first bring the branch up to date by merging or rebasing main into the branch, then test and review that. Now merging that into main will have no changes.

@TTT I'm referring to package.json. As with any merge, just because there's no conflicts doesn't mean the merge was correct. You have to look at what was merged and determine if it makes sense.

Oh. I see what you mean. By "ensure the merge went well", you mean "ensure the merge of package.json went well." (I thought you meant the overall branch merge.) I agree- that's an important step which people may typically skip with auto-merges. But after that's done, OP is still staring at conflicts on package-lock.json and wondering what to do. Step 1.5 might be "Don't worry about conflicts in package-lock.json at this point, just go to step 2, re-run and commit the merge after the lock file is rewritten.

@TTT Yes, step 1.5 is implied.
